# Oneplus One import from G Drive

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-drive, oneplus-one

I had an HTC one M8, used to backup everything to G Drive. I will receive my new Oneplus One tomorrow, and was wondering if I will be able to download my stuff back.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What kind of "stuff" are you backing up?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be any problem. You can simply download the G Drive app on the Oneplus One and download whatever you backed up.

The G-Drive is accessible on many different platforms so it shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: No. It comes with G Drive already installed and is the default